# TextMate: How can I switch 2 lines?

Tags: textmate

I recently migrated over from Notepad++ (and from Windows) and I am finding myself at an inconvenience without CTRL + T in Notepad++ which switches the current line with the previous line. I tried using Move selection (CMD + CTRL + ARROW), but it does not behave the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same as in Notepad++, <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Place your cursor at the beginning of the second line, press <kbd>⌃ T</kbd>, and the two lines will be transposed. Your cursor will also move down a line as well, enabling you to repeatedly transpose to move a line down several spots.

Comment: <3 - Do you have any other tips for using TextMate better?

Comment: @Doug Well, one of my favorite TM features is column selection - select some text on multiple columns, hit option, and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can also use <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.
Works from any point of the line, but will yield strange results if the line you're on has no line ending character.